# XML file not uploading through PHP on button click

Tags: php, file-upload

I am trying to upload a XML file through a PHP script to the parse that to XML. For whatever reason however, when I try and run the script I am not getting anywhere as the program tells me that there was no file uploaded. I am still very new to PHP and have followed a tutorial to code the onclick button. But I am not sure if I have done it correctly. The code for the button is:

```
<form action="convert.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            Select file to upload:
            <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
            <input type="submit" value="Convert file" name="submit">
</form>
```

and assigning the values to variables:

```
<?php
    $UploadDirectory = "uploads/";
    $FilePath = $UploadDirectory . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $uploadOK = 1;
    $FileType = strtolower(pathinfo($FilePath,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    
    if(isset($_POST["fileToUpload"]) || ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] < 10000)) // isset($_POST["submit"])
    {
        $check = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]['size'];
        if($check > 0)
        {
         //code to manipulate data
        }
        else
        {
            echo "No file chosen, or file too small";
            $uploadOK = 0;
        }
   }
```

I keep getting the echo statement as the output, and I am not sure why. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look at `$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["error"]` and check the value. You can get an explanation of what each number means at https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php. If the value is anything except 0 then you have a problem with the upload.

Comment: `isset($_POST["fileToUpload"])` should be `isset($_FILES["fileToUpload"])`

Comment: And the `||` should likely be an `&&` - surely it's not acceptable for only one of the conditions to be met? Also why are you checking the size in the first `if` and then checking it again in the second? It'd be more logical to check it all in one `if`, I would say.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the previous comments @ADyson and @brombeer for the assistance. I added the error script and can see that it is an issue with the php.ini file and the uploaded file exceeding the max upload. I have changed that and the program works!

Program now is:

```
<?php
    $UploadDirectory = "uploads/";
    $FilePath = $UploadDirectory . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $uploadOK = 1;
    $FileType = strtolower(pathinfo($FilePath,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    
    if(isset($_FILES["fileToUpload"]) && ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 10000))
    {
        $check = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]['size'];
        if($check > 0)
        {
         //code to manipulate data
        }
        else
        {
            echo "No file chosen, or file too small. See error for more details: Error code - " . $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["error"];
            $uploadOK = 0;
        }
   }
```